# What could be the loop invariant for the following algorithm (addition of natural numbers)

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to prove the correctness of the following function and I'm having trouble determining the loop invariant:

> **function** add(y, z) *//returns y + z*
>
> > x = 0; c = 0; d = 1;
> >     **while** (y > 0) **or** (z > 0) **or** (c > 0) **do**
> >
> > > a = y % 2;
> > >       b = z % 2;
> > >       **if** a **xor** b **xor** c **then** x = x + d;
> > >       c = (a **and** b) **or** (b **and** c) **or** (a **and** c);
> > >       d = 2d; y = ⌊y/2⌋; z = ⌊z/2⌋;
>
> **return**(x)

On my own, I thought (a **and**  b = c) is the loop invariant, because it was true for every iteration in the set of values of y and z that I've tested. I'm not really sure how that factoid is relevant in proving the correctness of the algorithm.